# I'm trying to delete NA values

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R, and I'm trying to remove NA values. However, when I use the na.omit() function, it deletes all the rows and returns zero observations. What am I doing wrong please? Here's the code;

```
Year2021_Trips_v2 <- Year2021_Trips_v2 %>% 
  na.omit()
```

Also, when I try another function aimed at the same thing, it does not delete any null values, but returns the number of rows exactly as it was. Here's the code for this;

```
Year2021_Trips_v2 <- Year2021_Trips[!(Year2021_Trips$name_start_station == "HQ QR" | Year2021_Trips$ride_length < 0),]
```

Comment: Coult you show the head of your data: e.g. `dput(head(yourdata))`

Answer (score 2):

You may use `is.na` on the whole data frame and calculate `rowSums` or `colSums` (`FALSE` has value `0` and `TRUE` value `1`). Compare them if they are equal to zero and do a logical subset. *Example:*

```
dat
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1 NA  9 NA
# 2  2  6 10 14
# 3  3  7 11 15
# 4  4  8 12 NA

## remove NA rows
dat[rowSums(is.na(dat)) == 0, ]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 2  2  6 10 14
# 3  3  7 11 15

## remove NA columns
dat[colSums(is.na(dat)) == 0]
#   V1 V3
# 1  1  9
# 2  2 10
# 3  3 11
# 4  4 12

## both
dat[rowSums(is.na(dat)) == 0, colSums(is.na(dat)) == 0]
#   V1 V3
# 2  2 10
# 3  3 11
```

Regarding your second issues, read `?Comparison` and note, that

> Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even
> to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA.
> Missing values can also result when character strings are compared and
> one is not valid in the current collation locale.

*Relevant example:*

```
c("A", NA, NA, "B", "A") == "A" 
# [1]  TRUE    NA    NA FALSE  TRUE

c("A", NA, NA, "B", "A") == "A" & !is.na(c("A", NA, NA, "B", "A"))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

c(-1, NA, NA, 2, -2) < 0
# [1]  TRUE    NA    NA FALSE  TRUE

c(-1, NA, NA, 2, -2) < 0 & !is.na(c(-1, NA, NA, 2, -2))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = 1:4, V2 = c(NA, 6L, 7L, 8L), V3 = 9:12, V4 = c(NA, 
14L, 15L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```